# QScrollArea contents not showing

Tags: qt

Below I present a full Qt project in which I was expecting to see a label and a button showing in a scrollarea, but it seems I'm not expressing myself as Qt expects. What Qt expects?

project.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled13
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    mainLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    scrollArea->setWidget(widget);

    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    widget->setLayout(hLayout);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("somelable");
    hLayout->addWidget(label);

    QPushButton *bt = new QPushButton("click");
    hLayout->addWidget(bt);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific code the problem is that you call

```
scrollArea->setWidget(widget);
```

before you add layout of the widget. **Move the above mentioned call to the end of the constructor** and *you see the label and the button inside the scrollarea*.

It's also mentioned in the [QScrollArea::setWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) documentation:

> Note that You must add the layout of widget before you call this
>   function; if you add it later, the widget will not be visible -
>   regardless of when you show() the scroll area.

Comment: Ok, got it. Would you mind post full code using the form `QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(widget);`? Or `scrollArea->setWidget(widget);` is the only way to go?

Comment: From the GUI semantics point of view they are different things: QScrollArea constructor takes a parent as an argument, setWidget method takes a widget as an argument which becomes the child of the scrollarea and is visible in its viewport.

Comment: I was suspicious about that :)